# Difference between StringBuffer and StringBuilder class

Tags: java, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I could get more on the internet and from Sun Java. But needed to get the clear difference with the help of an example?

`StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`

Whats the difference and when to prefer considering the response time.