# "StringBuffer is synchronized (or thread-safe) and StringBuilder is not", why does this make StringBuffer methods slower?

Tags: java, synchronization, thread-safety, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

After reading this - [What does 'synchronized' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085709/what-does-synchronized-mean) I was still unable to understand why StringBuffer would be slower than StringBuilder in a thread-safe environment. What extra time-consuming work does StringBuffer have to do that makes it slower?

Comment: You answer your own question. The StringBuffer is synchronized so it has to do more work that the other one does have to do. What makes it worse in this case is that 99% of the time its not needed.

Comment: ... and the thread that he links to pretty much explains why synchronization costs a bit more than code without synchronization.

Comment: Since the focus of the previous question was not on what extra work a synchronized method does, I had to assume there may be more than what was mentioned in the answers (to justify the very vehement 'Do not use StringBuffer unless you need Synchronization' statements I have come across). The selected answer below gives the information I needed. I think the question is justified.

Comment: might be interesting: [How do I prove programmatically that StringBuilder is not threadsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558432)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is some small overhead acquiring and releasing even an uncontended lock, and [lock elision](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp10185/index.html) won't work in `StringBuffer` even if most instances are not used cross-thread because an instance could be.

See http://book.javanb.com/java-threads-3rd/jthreads3-CHP-5-SECT-1.html for a description of what the VM has to do when acquiring and releasing locks.

Answer (score 2):

Making sure things are running in synch. Or, more to the point, out of synch.  Synchronizing a method call means two different invocations of that method (on that object if it is not static) have to take turns entering the method.  Thread B cannot enter method synchMeth until Thread A (already in the method) has finished.

The checks for whether a synchronized block has been locked or not, and by whom, take extra time.

Answer (score 2):

Read this from [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

> StringBuilder class provides an API
>   compatible with StringBuffer, but with
>   no guarantee of synchronization. This
>   class is designed for use as a drop-in
>   replacement for StringBuffer in places
>   where the string buffer was being used
>   by a single thread (as is generally
>   the case). Where possible, it is
>   recommended that this class be used in
>   preference to StringBuffer as it will
>   be faster under most implementations.

You must read this article on [StringBuffer vs. StringBuilder performance comparison](http://littletutorials.com/2008/07/16/stringbuffer-vs-stringbuilder-performance-comparison/)

> As of release JDK 5, this class has
>   been supplemented with an equivalent
>   class designed for use by a single
>   thread, {StringBuilder}. The
>   StringBuilder class should generally
>   be used in preference to this one, as
>   it supports all of the same operations
>   but it is faster, as it performs no
>   synchronization.

Additional Useful Link : [Difference between StringBuffer and StringBuilder class.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793380/difference-between-stringbuffer-and-stringbuilder-class)