# Which string concatenation technique is better in Java?

Tags: java, string, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)

In my code I am using String concatenation like below. I am doing code review so i need to do performance check.
    Please any one suggest that which one is better to use.

```
quoteTreeMap.put(index + CommonUtil.QUOTE_TREE_DOT + fundIndex + CommonUtil.QUOTE_TREE_DOT + lastIndex,buffer.toString());
```

so we are using this repeatedly with

```
index + CommonUtil.QUOTE_TREE_DOT + fundIndex + CommonUtil.QUOTE_TREE_DOT + lastIndex
```

only `lastIndex` this value will change, remaining is same for all.

How to write the code to give better performance?
can i declare

```
index + CommonUtil.QUOTE_TREE_DOT + fundIndex + CommonUtil.QUOTE_TREE_DOT
```

this as top like

```
String one=""index + CommonUtil.QUOTE_TREE_DOT + fundIndex + CommonUtil.QUOTE_TREE_DOT"
```

and can i use it as `one+lastIndex`?
for ref:

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
buffer.append(CommonUtil.QUOTE_TREE_GROSS_PREM);
buffer.append(CommonUtil.QUOTE_TREE_SPACE);
buffer.append(CommonUtil.QUOTE_TREE_EQUALS);
buffer.append(CommonUtil.QUOTE_TREE_SPACE);
buffer.append(chcCalBreakDownObj.getPremium().getGrossPrem());
quoteTreeMap.put(index + CommonUtil.QUOTE_TREE_DOT + fundIndex + CommonUtil.QUOTE_TREE_DOT + lastIndex, buffer.toString());
lastIndex++;
clearBuffer(buffer);
```

I am doing code review so i need to do performance check.
Please any one suggest that which one is better to use.

Comment: "I am doing code review so i need to do performance check." So what's stopping you?

Comment: Perhaps the worst-formatted question I've ever seen. Please read the editing help to avoid such catastrophes in the future.

Comment: " I am doing code review so i need to do performance check." I really don't get how the two are related. What is it? A code review or a performance review?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java

Answer (score 7):

You should use the `StringBuilder` because it does not involve creating a new `String` each time you append something to it.

Using the `+` operator to concatenate two `String`s create a new `String` object.

Please keep in mind that the main difference between `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` is that the latter is synchronized thus generally slower than the former.

Check out the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) if you are interested.

Comment: I don't think this is good advice. Of the three main alternatives (`String`, `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer`), the latter is probably the least appropriate. Also, the second paragraph is generally not true.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Java uses a StringBuilder or StringBuffer internally to do the concatenation anyway, doesn't it?

Comment: @cHao.. Yes, it does uses StringBuffer, AFAIK. But, it also creates a new String object for each concatenation it does.

Comment: @RohitJain It uses **StringBuilder** not StringBuffer internally for string concatenation

Comment: I think that using the Builder/Buffer classes are more versatile thus recommended.

Comment: @vishal_aim.. Ok. Wasn't exactly sure about that.

Comment: I don't get it guys. It may involve using `StringBuilder` internally but if you reference the concatenated string like in the example (`String one =`) and append something to it you end up with 2 new `String` objects.

Comment: @Adam: But he *doesn't* do that.  So there goes your main argument for using a buffer.  He's creating a prefix string, which can conceivably be used over and over.  It'd actually be the same amount of char shuffling (or even less!) to say `one + lastIndex` than to stuff everything into a new buffer each time.

Comment: And in the undefined future he **will** concatenate something to it. It always happens. The statement becomes long etc...I have seen it many times.

Comment: String one=""index + CommonUtil.QUOTE_TREE_DOT + fundIndex + CommonUtil.QUOTE_TREE

Comment: quoteTreeMap.put(one+lastIndex);

Comment: You just created 2 new `String` objects. The first being `one` the second is in the `put` method.

Comment: @sureshsudineedi: Sure you *can* do it.  It's legal Java.  The question is whether it's a good idea.  If you're going to do this just with Strings, you should either pre-create `one` (outside of any loops, preferably even outside of the function if possible) or do all the concatenation (including `lastIndex`) in one line.  Otherwise, a StringBuilder would probably be better.

Comment: or buffer.append(index);
  buffer.append(CommonUtil.QUOTE_TREE_DOT);

Comment: quoteTreeMap.put(buffer.toString()+lastIndex); can i do this?

Comment: @sureshsudineedi: `buffer.toString() + lastIndex` gets you the worst of both worlds.  (You get the ugliness of buffers, plus the inefficiency of creating extra strings.)  Don't do that.

Comment: ok. finally give the conclusion how to use it. only "latIndex" value will change remaining String is always same

Comment: finally i need to add it as a key vale to map

Comment: @sureshsudineedi: In that case, create `one` elsewhere (outside of the hot spots), and say `one + lastIndex`.

Comment: actually we need to add 1.1.2.1 as key vale to map. so last 1 value will change. remaining will be same

Answer (score 3):

To me it sounds like you're optimizing prematurely.

Focus on writing code that is easy to understand and maintain. Then profile it to discover where the bottlenecks are, and only then optimize.

The difference in performance between the two versions that you post is likely to be irrelevant.

P.S. In any event, it is worth understanding the differences between `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder`. See [Difference between StringBuffer and StringBuilder class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793380/difference-between-stringbuffer-and-stringbuilder-class)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`. `StringBuilder` is threadsafe for multiple threads and `StringBuffer` is usefull for single thread t increases the execution speed for single thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) or [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). The difference is that StringBuffer is threadsafe. If you use this only inside a method, you'll chose StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

you should profile the code first and find the real performance hogs. using StringBuilder in the part of the code shown might be quicker - but how much do you gain overall?

Answer (score 1):

If the resulting `one` will be the same for every iteration, pre-generate it outside of your loop.  Then you can say `one + lastIndex` without worrying so much about inefficiency; it'd be at least as efficient (CPUwise) as using a buffer explicitly.  Probably more so, as you're not rebuilding the string from scratch every time.  It does create one semi-extra String, but it's either that or a StringBuilder, so.

If `index`, `fundIndex`, or `CommonUtil.QUOTE_TREE_DOT` will be changing constantly, you have two choices:

- Use a StringBuilder to generate the result over several lines, or
- Do all the concatenation in one line.  ie: No `String one = ...`.

Just about any other solution will result in extra Strings.